Why minimum variance portfolio is used to construct factor models
I am reading Tsay's classic "Analysis of Financial Time Series" and I have seen him using minimum variance portfolio
Relevant passage on the minimum variance portfolio here (Chapter 9, Page 411）

And "factor mimicking portfolio" here. (Chapter 9, Page 419）

Question: I'm a bit confused why we need to find the weights that minimize the portfolio variance as the weights to compute the factor returns. I'd think that if we want to define one factor, we want it to explain as much variance as possible, rather than minimizing the variance?

What is the name of the section/subsection of the chapter by Tsay? I just want to see what is the goal he is trying to accomplish here.

@KaiSqDist added some more information to the question

Hi: what does $D$ represent in the "factor mimicking" portfolio ?

@markleeds $D = diag( 1/\sigma_i^2 )$ where $\sigma_i$ is the stock specific variance. (variance can't be explained by the factor model)

So the factor model was already fit and that's how $D$ was obtained ? I'm confused on the steps. Apologies for these possibly bad questions.

You are right that we select factors that explain a big part of market  variance. But once you have identified the factors how do you use them to build a portfolio? In the absence of any insight as to which factors have the highest expected returns (difficult to know), one reasonable idea is simply to combine them together so as to minimize the variance of the portfolio. MinVar is just Markowitz with expected returns assumed equal.


I'm a bit confused why we need to find the weights that minimize the portfolio variance as the weights to compute the factor returns. I'd think that if we want to define one factor, we want it to explain as much variance as possible, rather than minimizing the variance?

As a casual answer, idiosyncratic risk is diversifiable;  common factor risk is non-diversifiable.
In the equation
$$
w = \frac{\Sigma^{-1} \boldsymbol{1}}{\boldsymbol{1}^{\textrm{T}}\Sigma^{-1} \boldsymbol{1}} ~,
$$
the numerator $\Sigma^{-1} \boldsymbol{1}$ is a precision weighted combination of the assets and the denominator $ \boldsymbol{1}^{\textrm{T}}\Sigma^{-1} \boldsymbol{1} $ is a scaling factor for portfolio weights $w$.
If all assets are equally impacted by the market return,
$$
r_i = r_{\textrm{market}} + \ldots + \epsilon_{i}~,
$$
a reasonable attempt at an estimate of $r_{\textrm{market}}$ is
$$
{\hat{~r~}_\textrm{market}} \propto \Sigma^{-1}r ~ .
$$
Not considering $\textrm{Var}\left(\epsilon_i\right)$ results in noisier estimates of $r_{\textrm{market}}$ . We don't know $\textrm{Var}\left(\epsilon_i\right)$, so $\sigma_{i,i}^{-1}$ is a work-around.

Edit
You need factor loadings to estimate factor returns, and you need factor returns to estimate factor loadings.
Here, $\boldsymbol{1}$ is a vector of loadings on market return.
$$
\begin{aligned}
r_i &= l_{i,\textrm{market}} &r_{\textrm{market}} + \ldots + \epsilon_{i} \\ 
r_i &= 1 &r_{\textrm{market}} + \ldots + \epsilon_{i}
\end{aligned}
$$
